# Python BigQuery API and accessing tables in another project

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a notebook, where I have permissions to create a notebook (but cannot do so in other project) as data is in another project. How can I access the data across projects?

```
import datetime
import requests
import os
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.exceptions import NotFound
import datetime
import logging as log

client = bigquery.Client()
query = """CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `anotherproject.user.table` AS...."""
query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request.
```

I cannot find much on the way I could authenticate to get in via the google cloud API?

Here is the error:

```
Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: Table anotherproject.user.table: User does not have permission to query table anotherproject.user.table.
```

Comment: Your client needs to be authenticated to the project you want to access. If you need to query different tables in different projects, your service account should have permissions in both projects.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your client needs to be authenticated to the project which you want to access. If you need to query different tables in different projects, your service account should have permissions in both the projects. So, follow the below steps to resolve your issue:

**Step-1**: Create a `Service Account(SA)` with the required permissions in a `Project-2`(where you are trying to execute an API code). For example, I have created a service account with a `BigQuery Admin role` and also created a JSON key for that SA.

[image]

**Step-2**: Go to `IAM` in `Project-1`(where your BigQuery table resides) -> Click Add -> In a principal field, add that Service Account(SA) `email ID` which you have created in `Project-2` and select a role based on your use case. For example, I have selected a `BigQuery Data Viewer` role.

[image]

**Step-3**: Next, provide authentication credentials to your application code by setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. For example, if it is Linux, run export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="KEY_PATH", replace `KEY_PATH` with the path of the JSON file that contains your Project-2 service account key.

**Step-4**: Finally, execute your BigQuery API code in Cloud shell/ Notebook and test it. For example, I have executed the following code and got a result:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
 
# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()
 
query = """
 SELECT * FROM `project-id.dataset-name.table-name`;
"""
query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request.
 
print("The query data:")
for row in query_job:
   # Row values can be accessed by field name or index.
   print("name={}, count={}".format(row[0], row["Column-name"]))
```

Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) for more information about setting up authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the permissions to the dataset in python using the dataset.access_entries property with the access controls for a dataset. Then call the client.update_dataset() function to update the property. There is a google page showing you how to do this here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls#granting_access_to_a_dataset