# use different project for bigquery data than for the billing of queries

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-python

I'm currently querying a project (call it `data_project`) in bigquery through the python SDK.
For several reasons I want to restrict the access to this project to a full read-only and switch the queries itself to another project (call it `quota_project`) without having to specify the project in the query explicitly.

This means I don't want to do `` SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table` ``  but rather keep `` SELECT * FROM `dataset.table` ``  while switching the project it is billed against.

Could be relevant here (but should not imho): `quota_project` has reservations.

To my understanding, this would be allowed by the option [`quota_project_id`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html#google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials.with_quota_project) while initializing the credentials.

I tried the following two options which I thought make sense from following the documentation, neither of it worked out (both queries have been billed to the data_project):

```
import google.cloud.bigquery as bq
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(credential_path, scopes)

# option 1
c = creds.with_quota_project(quota_project)
client = bq.client.Client(credentials=c)
client.query("SELECT 1").result().to_dataframe()

# option 2
client = bq.client.Client(
    credentials=creds, client_options={"quota_project_id": quota_project}
)
client.query("SELECT 1").result().to_dataframe()
```

Is anybody aware of how to achieve this? Or am I misunderstanding the intention of a "quota project"?

Comment: The method “with_quota_project” is used to add a quota from your specific project and to return a copy of these credentials.
You can refer to this [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/main/google/oauth2/service_account.py) for more detailed implementation of this method which is used to return these google.auth credentials.Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `add a quota from project` - I understand this routine as `credentials still using the project id but billing on a different project` (which seems reasonable as the linked credentials class is initiated using project_id and quota_project_id).

Answer (score 2):

A quota project is used by client libraries, etc. for billing purposes. You can set the [quota project](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/set-quota-project) using the CLI:

`gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project my-quota-project`

To set Application default credentials, you have to run the command:

`gcloud auth application-default login`

The existing application default credentials must have the `serviceusage.services.use` permission on the given project.

You can refer to this regarding to [BigQuery quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) and this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952773/who-pays-query-costs-on-datasets-across-multiple-users-in-bigquery/53952885#53952885) to know more about query costs in BigQuery.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. As the code suggests, there are already authenticated credentials which I use (and yes, tried setting the quota project as well via cli, didn't work out either). I'm searching for a reason why adding the quota project manually doesn't lead to its application (or a comment why I'm mistaking the docs, understanding currently that I can have  a different GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID - i.e. default project to use for datasets if not is hardcoded in the queries - and quota project). I'll try out adding serviceusage consumer explicit, even if this hadn't raised an error.

Comment: Update: I checked it, I'm owner on the project I want to use for billing and have Job User permission on the project I want to use as default project - Confused why the code is not working as expected.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? When trying to set a quota-project using CLI can you make sure you have authenticated with proper credentials? For example using a service account.

Comment: No I don't and yes, I receive the data, just not through the proper project. I'm looking for an answer whether this is the right approach taken and for a MWE to use different default project and billing project together (if that's possible, otherwise searching for a clear no).

Comment: `quota_project_id` is project ID used for quota and billing. If you are a billing administrator on only one Cloud Billing account, new projects you create are automatically linked to your existing Cloud Billing account. For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project). To query data from another project this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71173673/python-bigquery-api-and-accessing-tables-in-another-project/71189292#71189292) can be referred.